# java.util.HashSet int iteration order

Tags: java

When i run the code which shown in below, the output is [50, 20, 5, 40, 10, 30].
I didn't understand this order. Why the output is not [10, 5, 20, 30, 40, 50] ?

```
List list = Arrays.asList(10, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
System.out.println(new HashSet(list));
```

Comment: `HashSet` doesn't preserve insertion order !

Comment: Because iteration order of HashSets is undefined. See the Javadoc, which you should have consulted before posting. -1

Comment: EJP you read my comment under Baadshah's answer. Reputation musn't be an aim, my aim is sharing. Read raptortech97's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Docs says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. This class permits the null element.

go for [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Comment: I don't want to sort. I read doc but when I tried two other computer I got the same output. If the order is not guaranteed, how it is same?

Comment: As you add and remove elements over time, the iteration order may change. You should never rely on the iteration order of Hashset, as it "makes no guarantees as to the iteration order," although in practice if you make a new Hashset with the default constructor and you add the same elements you end up with the same iteration order.

Comment: raptortech you gave the answer which I was wondering and wanted to hear. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

`HashSet` doesn't maintain insertion order. What you need is a `LinkedHashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

The `HashSet` class does not guarantee the order in which you have entered the data.

If you **do not** put your `List` in the `HashSet` and instead continue with `List` you will get the order in which you are adding the values in it.

You can use `LinkedHashSet` to keep the insertion order.

If you want to **sort** the `List` then you can use `Collections.sort()`. (Extra information, ignore if you do not need it)

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Java.util.HashSet makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Comment: TreeSet won't help because OP needs insertion order.

Comment: oopse .. thanks for the correction..@RaviThapliyal

Comment: LinkedHashSet can be used ..